# How can I compress Mic input using a virtual sound card?

Tags: microphone, gain

Is there a way to set up a compression VST on the default input of my mac? e.g. I want to make a skype call and I have my USB soundcard as mic input, is there a way to set up the default input as my soundcard passing through a compressor (for high gain purposes)?

Comment: what you want is a standalone compressor. Sometimes soundcards also includes mixer + effects (which is apparently not your case). I can't answer precisely to your answer but it is possible. Note that skype already compress your sound. Best !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, however, unless your undefined 'USB soundcard' has an AU-compatible front-end or its own input gain stage, then you'd have to use something like [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/).
You can't easily use VSTs on the input without an ASIO/VST controller & even then, they would normally be strapped to the output... which you would then need something like Audio Hijack to re-route...

*[Previously, SoundFlower (freeware) would be the go-to solution, but since Mavericks it is no longer stable]*